# Show multiple forms on a single page without refresh django template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am planning on creating a single page with toolbar on the top.

[image: http://i66.tinypic.com/102nts3.jpg]

I want to click on different buttons on the toolbar and get the form without a page refresh.

Is there a way I can do it with Django templates using `if` conditions (such as below)? And is the page refresh necessary?

```
{% if new_button_pressed %}
{% else %}
```

**views.py**

```
    if request.POST.get('new'):
        logger.info('user clicked new')
    elif request.POST.get('last'):
        logger.info('user clicked due next')
    elif request.POST.get('previous'):
        logger.info('user clicked due next')
```

Is it doable or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django is a (server) backend framework. Which means that it generates the code for the the client to process. You cannot edit the contents without it reloading the page. So.. what you have in your view is not going to work just like that.

What you will need is Javascript. AJAX (if you want to do a request to the server without reloading) or jQuery if you have already rendered everything and just want to show it.

You might want to use a Javascript framework like VueJS, ReactJS or AngularJS.

An example is right here: https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/